# IIS server certificate error: The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address

Tags: iis, https, server, certificate, self-signed

I am using IIS 6.1, with HTTPS enabled, using a self-signed certificate.  When using IE to browse to the site, I get an error "The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address", if I use the server IP, "localhost", or "127.0.0.1" as the host name.  The error disappears when I use the server name as the host name.

How can I get around this error when using IP, "localhost", or "127.0.0.1"?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  Certificates only apply to the hostnames they're issued for.  Make a certificate that matches the hostname.

Comment: No real world web site would be accessed via localhost or 127.0.0.1. So try to learn how a proper certificate works in general.